# Add custom beans to Spring context

Tags: java, spring

I have some classes, with a custom annotation, that shouldn't be instantiated (abstract class, and it's just a subcomponents for a real beans). But on top of this classes, on runtime, on context initialization phase, I want to put extra beans into application context.

So, basically I need to scan classpath, process results, and introduce new beans into curent application context.

It seems that spring-mvc, spring-tasks and spring-integration are doing this (I tried to learn it from sources - no luck)

I found that I can create my own `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, scan classpath and call `registerSingleton` for my custom bean. But I'm not sure that it's a good way for introducing new beans (seems that it's used only for postprocess of exising beans only). And I believe there are some Spring internal tools that I may reuse to simplify process.

What is a conventional way to introduce extra beans on Spring context initialization?

Comment: perhaps  this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

Comment: It's not a problem to find such classes, I just don't know how to do it inside Sprign initialization phase and how to make a new bean for such classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observation is actually correct, [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) is one of the two ways Spring provides a mechanism to modify the bean definition/instances before making them available to the application(the other is using [BeanPostProcessors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html))

You can absolutely use BeanFactoryPostProcessors to add/modify bean definitions, here is one sample from Spring Integration codebase that adds a errorChannel if not explicitly specified by a user, you can probably use a similar code for registering your new beans:

```
    RootBeanDefinition errorChannelDef = new RootBeanDefinition();
    errorChannelDef.setBeanClassName(IntegrationNamespaceUtils.BASE_PACKAGE
            + ".channel.PublishSubscribeChannel");
    BeanDefinitionHolder errorChannelHolder = new BeanDefinitionHolder(errorChannelDef,
            IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME);
    BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.registerBeanDefinition(errorChannelHolder, registry);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to include custom annotated classes as bean definitions:

- Annotate the custom annotation with @Component
- Add a include filter with type annotation to `<context:component-scan/>`

for example:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.example.Annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Then you can use a `BeanPostProcessor` to instantiate them, for example:

```
public class CustomAnnotationBeanPostProcessor extends InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter


         @Override
            public Object postProcessBeforeInstantiation(Class<?> beanClass, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (beanClass.isAnnotationPresent(org.example.Annotation.class)) {
                    Object bean  = createBeanInstance();
                    ...
                    return bean:
                }
                return null;
            } 
    }
```

Or use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to process the `ScannedGenericBeanDefinitions`.

See `AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors()` for sample code of internal Spring annotation postprocessors.