# How to set bean property to property of another bean

Tags: java, spring, autowired

This is my spring configuration file :

```
   <bean id="controller" class="com.sample.controller.Controller">
       <property name="message" value="Controller1"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="controller2" class="com.sample.controller.Controller2">
       <property name="message" value="#{controller.message}"/>
   </bean>
```

And the code :

```
 ApplicationContext context = 
         new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

  Controller obj = (Controller) context.getBean("controller");

  System.out.println(obj.getMessage());
  obj.message = "Controller1 changed!";

  Controller2 obj2 = (Controller2) context.getBean("controller2");
  System.out.println(obj2.getMessage());
```

I wanted the output to be :

```
Controller1
Controller1 changed!
```

but it is

```
Controller1
Controller1
```

Is there a simpler way to get the updated value other than injecting Controller into Controller1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define property  `message` as bean it self

```
<bean id="message" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="Controller1"/>
</bean>
```

and change the original bean configuration

```
   <bean id="controller" class="com.sample.controller.Controller">
       <property name="message" ref="message"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="controller2" class="com.sample.controller.Controller2">
       <property name="message" ref="message"/>
   </bean>
```

Now change the message in java code by

```
  String obj = (String) context.getBean("message");
```

and [add it back to context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720579/add-custom-beans-to-spring-context)

Comment: Can you elaborate? Did you mean another bean (defined in config also) that just has 'message' as a member variable?

Comment: That should work. Thanks for the solution! Is there no other way for this? This way, I have to list out all the member variables I want to pass from one class to another (like lists, maps).

Comment: yeah you could have a Map as bean as well

Comment: How do you specify the type of the List? Like a list of Strings or List of Foo? I don't have any elements to add in 'ref' initially so there should be some way to tell Spring what kind of objects I will be adding to the list. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it out and turns out I don't have to specify the class type.

Comment: could you please elaborate

Comment: I added this line and did not have to specify what type of list I a am using in the class. It works for List<String> or List<Foo> `<bean id="someList" class="java.util.ArrayList"></bean>`